# Can access iis web page externally via IP but via domain name I receive a 404 error

Tags: web-applications, iis-7, dns

I have a strange IIS 7 issue, and after extensive googling I can't find anything similar to help prompt to an answer.

We have a website application that resolves via the web, externally to:

```
http://12.34.56.78/ourwebapp - that works just fine, it hits the default web page.
```

However, when we try to resolve via domain name:

```
http://subdomain.ourdomain.com/ourwebapp - it doesn't hit the default web page
```

and instead, reaches the web server but an IIS 404 - File or directory not found occurs.

The A record is correct and resolves to the IP address (checked and tested). It also suggests it's reaching the web server anyway because of the error that's displayed.

Unsure as to how to resolve the problem?